# wordpress have value of add_meta_box and used in template

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have created new fields with `add_meta_box` in the administrator. but now how I use them in the template.

tried with `$wp_query-> the_post()` and in the array this field is not created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get value of new field(Assuming text field) of meta-box on frontend in page template. Place following code in your template file.

```
<?php  
$field_value =get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'your-field-name',true);
echo $field_value;
?>
```

Make sure to change with your exact field name at "your-field-name" in above code.